# Error Creating View From Importing MysqlDump

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I don't speak SQL... Please, anybody help me.  What does this mean?:

Error
SQL query:

```
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED *//*!50001 VIEW `v_sr_videntity` AS select `t`.`c_id` AS `ID`,`User`.`c_id` AS `UserID`,`videntityfingerprint`.`ID` AS `VIdentityFingerPrintID`,`videntityfingerprint`.`FingerPrintID` AS `FingerPrintID`,`videntityfingerprint`.`FingerPrintFingerPrint` AS `FingerPrintFingerPrint` from ((`t_SR_u_Identity` `t` join `t_SR_u_User` `User` on((`User`.`c_r_Identity` = `t`.`c_id`))) join `vi_sr_videntity_0` `VIdentityFingerPrint` on((`videntityfingerprint`.`c_r_Identity` = `t`.`c_id`))) */;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'videntityfingerprint.ID' in 'field list'
```

What does this mean?  What is it expecting?  How do I fix it?  This file was created by mysqldump, so why are there errors when I import it?

Answer (score -1):

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1689

Comment: The bug provided in the link describes a different issue. Please do not simply answer a question with a link. You can provide links in support of an actual answer. But a link is not an answer.